# What that mean this message when I update tensorflow and keras in Anaconda Prompt ? Is wrong or Okay?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Ruben>conda update tensorflow
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

C:\Users\Ruben>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\Ruben>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\Ruben>SET platform=

C:\Users\Ruben>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\Ruben>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\Ruben>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\Ruben>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: El sistema no ha podido encontrar la clave o el valor del Registro
especificados.

C:\Users\Ruben>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\Ruben>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
El sistema no encuentra la etiqueta por lotes especificada: End

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Ruben>

Comment: If you like, however, to remove that warning message for upcoming installs have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946233/11322237)

Answer (score 2):

ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"

Got this warning message after i installed KERAS using Anaconda Prompt. Just make sure KERAS is the last you install otherwise you won't be able to install others eg. Pyinstaller or Nuitka.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem too, but it happens with the Pymc3 library.