# Anaconda Installation: ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

Tags: anaconda

I installed `anaconda` and setup a new environment from a `yml` file.

That is fine.

Then i tried to open the prompt window of my new environment and i get the following output every single time.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET MSSdk=1
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET platform=
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>if defined platform (set
>   "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0"
>   )  ELSE (set
>   "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0"
>   /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B" ERROR: The system was unable
>   to find the specified registry key or value.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "" == "" ( ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in
>   registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work" 
>   GOTO End ) "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS
>   env var - your compiler may not work" The system cannot find the batch
>   label specified - End

I have no clue how to fix this. Any help ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I just removed the script called vs2015_compiler_vars from $CONDAHOME/etc/conda/activate.d and it worked fine. No issues till now, will report if there are any.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is about showing the steps of the proposed solution of @Arpan and that is deleting the batch file named "vs2015_compiler_vars".

### How I managed to solve this in Windows

#### 1) Set option to view hidden files

#### 2) Go to this location

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\etc\conda\activate.d
```

#### 3) Delete batch file named "vs2015_compiler_vars"

======================================================

### How I think to solve this in Linux

Find the file named "vs2015_compiler_vars" and delete it.

As sugested by @Arpan, the file may be found at

```
$CONDAHOME/etc/conda/activate.d
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Arpan removing vs2015_compiler_vars from $CONDAHOME/etc/conda/activate.d helped.

Answer (score 0):

launch Anaconda navigator-->under environments tab --> select uninstalled from the dropdown--> then search for the installed Visual studio version VS and enable it.. apply and exit
then try reinstall teraflow and keras from command..
should work