# How do I install tensorflow_text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-10

I'm trying to reproduce the [notebook on Google Multilingual Universal Encoder](http://Cross-Lingual%20Similarity%20and%20Semantic%20Search%20Engine%20with%20TF-Hub%20Multilingual%20Universal%20Encoder). However by downloading the necessary libraries as `tensorflow_text`:

```
%%capture
#@title Setup Environment
# Install the latest Tensorflow version.
!pip3 install tensorflow_text
```

or

```
!python -m pip install tensorflow_text
```

And I get in jupyter:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-399dd4157896> in <module>
      8 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
      9 import tensorflow_hub as hub
---> 10 from tensorflow_text import SentencepieceTokenizer
     11 import sklearn.metrics.pairwise
     12 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_text'
```

I tried to install it with `python -m pip install tensorflow-text`, but it gave me:

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python -m pip install tensorflow-text
Collecting tensorflow-text
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I also tried `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>set "KERAS_BACKEND="

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python C:\Users\antoi\.conda\envs\seg_env\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>del temp.txt

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>SET platform=

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation\sentiment>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

## Versions

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation>python -m pip list | findstr tensorflow
tensorflow           2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0
```

And python:

```
(seg_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\Segmentation>python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  6 2019, 07:03:06) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm on Windows 10

Comment: tensorflow_text is NOT (yet) available for Windows.
https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/44

Answer (score 6):

This should work: `pip install tensorflow-text`

Comment: Hmm, I get `No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text`

Comment: This package requires TensorFlow 2.0. From documentation: `TensorFlow Text requires TensorFlow 2.0` This could be the reason

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I read it as well in the docs. However I now have tensorflow 2.1.0 and python 3.6.7 and still have the error

Comment: I have tensorflow 2.2 .. ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text

Comment: I can see that there are only linux and mac os versions under `https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.2.1/#files` and not for windows. Am I correct?

Comment: Works fine for mac

Comment: Not of Mac M1 @ChirayuChamoli, See https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/837

Answer (score 3):

I had `TensorFlow` version 2.5 and used the below command and it worked.

```
pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.5
```

Comment: Works for me with `pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.9` using TensorFlow version 2.9.3

Answer (score 1):

The installation of `tensorflow-text` (imported as `tensorflow_text`) through pip was not possible for Windows until version 2.4.1 (released Dec 2020).

For Windows, you can now do: `pip install tensorflow-text` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

## PART 1: INSTALLING TENSORFLOW

In order to install tensorflow with Anaconda do the following:

#### Step 1

Download Anaconda from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and install it.

#### Step 2

Open Anaconda Prompt **as Administrator**

#### Step 3

Create a conda virtual environment named tensorflow_env with the following command:

```
C:\> conda create -n tensorflow_env python=3.7
```

#### Step 4

Activate the conda environment

```
C:\> activate tensorflow_env
```

Now your prompt should change to

```
(tensorflow_env) C:\>
```

#### Step 5

Install TensorFlow into your Anaconda environment

```
(tensorflow_env) C:\> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

#### Step 6 (Optional)

Check that you have installed Anaconda

```
(tensorflow_env) C:\>python
>>> import tensorflow
>>> print(tensorflow. __version__)
```

The steps described below are from [this article](https://medium.com/@potassium_hydride/install-tensorflow-and-keras-with-anaconda-for-pycharm-on-windows-step-5fa33b38fd9).
This was the way I successfully installed TensforFlow on my device.

==============================================

## PART 2: Fixing the warning

```
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
```

### How I managed to solve this in Windows

#### 1) Set option to view hidden files

#### 2) Go to this location

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\etc\conda\activate.d
```

#### 3) Delete batch file named "vs2015_compiler_vars"

=========

### How I think to solve this in Linux

Find the file named "vs2015_compiler_vars" and delete it.

As sugested in a comment at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57082951/11322237) by @Arpan, the file may be found at

```
$CONDAHOME/etc/conda/activate.d
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the packages provided by the TensorFlow-Text project that apparently re-surfaces from time to time. See [Issue 89](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/89) and [Issue 291](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/291) in their GitHub.

You can either wait until this is resolved (again), or try to build the package from source.