# Tensorflow Load_Model not working on GCP due to Contrib Ops

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've deployed a flask app using machine learning to GCP. When ever I run it on my machine it works fine. However whenever I deploy the app and run it there I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'MLCLSTM' in binary running on localhost. 
Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. 
Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) 
`tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are 
lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

Through my research I haven't found many problems like this.
If any of you could help figure out how to load my model it would be highly appreciated.

The requirements file looks like

```
certifi==2021.10.8
chardet==4.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.7
click==8.0.3
cycler==0.10.0
Flask==2.0.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
joblib==1.1.0
jsonpickle==2.0.0
kiwisolver==1.3.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.4.3
midi2audio==0.1.1
more-itertools==8.10.0
music21==7.1.0
numpy==1.19.3
Pillow==8.4.0
pyparsing==3.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
requests==2.26.0
six
urllib3==1.26.7
webcolors==1.11.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
tensorflow
h5py
grpcio
numpy
```

BTW: The model exists in the directory and I'm loading it by tf.keras.load_model with tensorflow 2.6.0 I believe

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/swlh/deep-learning-in-production-a-flask-approach-7a8e839c25b9

Comment: @Ulto4 Thanks but it's not working.

Comment: It looks similar to this issue [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38597](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38597)
So, you could try installing and importing tensorflow_text as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054142/13171940)