Encountering issue with installing tensorflow-text in Both Jupyter Notebook and Google Colab
I'm facing a ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text Jupyter Notebook when i try to insatll it. In Google Colab when im loading tensorflow_hub, so when i install tensorflow-text then tensorflow_hub not working & when install tensorflow_hub then tensorflow-text not working.
Jupyter Notebook image Google Colab image 1 Google Colab image 2
I tried installing tensorflow_text using pip install tensorflow_text in both Jupyter Notebook and Google Colab. I expected the library to be imported successfully in my code. Additionally, I experimented with installing specific versions of tensorflow_text but still encountered the same error.

After installing any libraries make sure to restart the kernel.

doesn't work for me.

@impulsive do refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267745/how-do-i-install-tensorflow-text
hoping it helps..

I have already checked this post.
