# To activate a repository using conda, getting this error : "Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env v"

Tags: github, anaconda, data-science, conda

I am trying to clone a repository from GitHub. I have cloned the repo by using the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/ericmjl/bayesian-stats-modelling-tutorial
```

Next, I have installed all the required packages by using the following command :

```
conda env create -f binder/environment.yml
```

Now I am trying to activate the environment by using the following command :

```
conda activate <Name of the repo>
```

But getting this error :

```
C:\Users\vyasa>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\vyasa>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\vyasa>SET platform=

C:\Users\vyasa>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\vyasa>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\vyasa>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\vyasa>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\vyasa>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\vyasa>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End

(bayesian-modelling-tutorial) C:\Users\vyasa>conda activate bayesian-modelling-tutorial

C:\Users\vyasa>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\vyasa>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\vyasa>SET platform=

C:\Users\vyasa>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\vyasa>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\vyasa>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\vyasa>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\vyasa>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\vyasa>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

Comment: Please share the github repo link or the content of `environment.yml`

Comment: @FlyingTeller : [Link] ( https://github.com/ericmjl/bayesian-stats-modelling-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the warning

```
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
```

I already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946233/11322237). However, I will copy the instructions here too.

### How I managed to solve this in Windows

#### 1) Set option to view hidden files

#### 2) Go to this location

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\etc\conda\activate.d
```

#### 3) Delete batch file named "vs2015_compiler_vars"

======================================================

### How I think to solve this in Linux

Find the file named "vs2015_compiler_vars" and delete it.

As sugested by @Arpan in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57082951/11322237), the file may be found at

```
$CONDAHOME/etc/conda/activate.d
```