# Update Python in Anaconda: registry key error

Tags: python, conda, updates

I tried to update python (3.7.7) to the latest version (3.8.2) through Anaconda prompt but received the error message below (after running `conda update python` a few times).

```
(base) C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>conda update python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>SET platform=

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" )

C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>if "" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End

(base) C:\Users\Dat Nguyen>python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

Please send help. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this solution that I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082951/anaconda-installation-error-the-system-was-unable-to-find-the-specified-regist  and removed the batch file named "vs2015_compiler_vars" but it still doesn't work. After rerunning `conda update python` it just shows "All requested package already installed" but Python's version is still 3.7.7.

Comment: Updating your **base** Python is usually a bad idea (frequently ends in borked Conda installs). Create a new env instead.